# How to use breakpoints for theme spacing in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there way to define [theme spacing](https://material-ui.com/customization/spacing/#custom-spacing) using breakpoints? Something like

```
spacing: {
   [defaultTheme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: 4
   [defaultTheme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: 8
   ...
}
```

Or like it's done in [typography](https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes)

I know I can use `rem`, but that does not suits me

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
spacing: calc(100vw / x);
```

x will be a number like 70 for example.

It will update itself with screen resizing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that will not help help me. I want spacing be one of predefined value and not changing with every px